# Losing lives on candy crush

Tags: candy-crush-saga

I have a lot of friends who give me lives it shows that I have several and when I hit candy crush under my Facebook it does not add them and they are gone. What happens to them?

Comment: I'm just guessing: candy crush got rid of it. They either have a cap to the limit or the thing I said first.

Answer (score 2):

You can't collect lives from the facebook website. To collect the lives, open the game. There will be a mail box at the right side. Click on it. You will see a number of things like your friends asking for lives and friends who gave you life. To get the lives, press accept button there.

Note- If your present lives are 5 and you collect 1 live, it will not become 6, i.e., they will remain 5.